# JPA bidirectional @OneToOne and cascade merge

Tags: java, jpa

If I have those two entities:

```
@Entity class A { 
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy = "a") B b; 
    //getters+setters
}
@Entity class B { 
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE) A a; 
    //getters+setters
}
```

Does the JPA specification *guarantee* this?

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.setB(b);
b.setA(a);
A managedA = entityManager.merge(a);
// after commit, managedA will have a reference to a managed B which JPA implementation will link to managedA instead of original unmanaged A
Assert.assertTrue(managedA.getB().getA() == managedA);
```

My understanding is that it works (at least with latest EclipseLink, at least sometimes), but that the spec doesn't guarantee that.

Counter-examples / spec excerpts welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the JPA specification does not guarantee that. In fact in most cases the semantics for merge() is that it returns a new instance  - a managed instance created by the entity manager, into which the state of the given object is merged - but this is just a simplification. If it attached the very object that you put in then the method could actually return void (like the persist() method does). I have no clue why it was designed like that - it was actually a bit of a pain in the ass to have this different semantics and it took us some time to encapsulate the desired behavior in our application code.

The actual semantics of the merge operation can be found in **3.2.7.1 Merging Detached Entity State of the JPA specifications** final release. It does behave differently depending on the object that you put in and on the current persistence context.

Side note: An entity does become detached as soon as the transaction is over as long as you don't use an extended persistence context.

Please also note that you should usually not compare objects using the == operator since this is actually not the semantics you desire for your object comparison (jvm identity is not equal to business object identity)

Comment: The == comparison is on purpose here. I want to know for sure whether I get the same reference. equals() is guaranteed by the spec for this case.

Comment: 3.2.7.1 from JPA 2 spec says the following, which seems to indicate that the assertions in my question would be guaranteed after all. What do you think? "If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity Y, where cascade=MERGE
or cascade=ALL is not specified, then navigation of the same association from X' yields a
reference to a managed object Y' with the same persistent identity as Y"

Comment: Ok, I got your point with the == operator. Just wanted to point that out because many people mix that up. And about your citation: "...the same persistent identity as Y" -> persistent identity! That is not JVM object identity. You don't necessarily get the same object back. My advise is to always expect a different object.

Comment: Ok, but it also says "to a *managed* object Y'". In the same persistence context, this means the same reference, an entity manager can't have multiple objects for the same database row. Now, the real reason why I'm asking this is that I'd want to know if I *have to* write this: managedA.getB().setA(managedA). After this discussion, I think I don't.

Comment: Your probably right. But why didn't you clearify on the "real reason" why you're asking? I could have told you that you don't have to wire up the managed entities again after calling merge(). You wired them before passing them to the merge method, so the object that is returned by merge (whether or not it may be the same instance is actually of no importance then) of course represents the graph of objects (now managed objects) that you passed in. Otherwise it would be quite a hassle to deal with deeper object graphs.

Comment: Because I'm not just interested in the solution of my original problem, I want to know for sure that this is the expected way of doing it (=what the specification guarantees about it).

Comment: +1 for your clues (+5 if I could), but I can't accept it as the answer as is

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the upvote (you could upvote one of the comments, if u like). The discussion also revealed some blurry points in my vision of JPA inner workings. Let's see if somebody else can chip in something useful.